# NodeJs - VueJs - Cannot GET /routes in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, production

I want to put in production my website developped in NodeJs (express) and VueJs (2.6.11).

My Folder look like that :

```
/MyNodeJsApp
     - MyVueJsApp
```

I have this in my vue.config.js

```
outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")
```

So when I `npm run build` it goes on a public directory at the root of my project.

My server.js is like that :

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require('cors')

require('rootpath')();
const basicAuth = require('app/helpers/basic-auth');
const errorHandler = require('app/helpers/error-handler');
const app = express();

// parse requests of content-type: application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// parse requests of content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Allow cors
app.use(cors())

// use basic HTTP auth to secure the api
app.use(basicAuth);

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// all Page routes
require("./app/routes/pageitem.routes.js")(app);
require("./app/routes/actualite.routes.js")(app);
require("./app/routes/user.routes.js")(app);
require("./app/routes/contact.routes.js")(app);

//We'll use the public directory to serve the Vue app
app.use(express.static('public'));

// set port, listen for requests
const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

All the routes in my Nodejs api contain the same prefixe `/api/` like so :

```
module.exports = app => {
    const actualites = require("../controllers/actualite.controller.js");
  
    // Retrieve all Pages
    app.get("/api/actualites", actualites.findAll);

    app.get("/api/actualites/type", actualites.getAllType);

    app.get("/api/actualites/type/:type", actualites.findFromType);

    // Retrieve a single Page with customerId
    app.get("/api/actualites/:id", actualites.findOne);
  };
```

This is my VueJsapp/router/index.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Missions from '../views/Missions.vue'
import VousEtes from '../views/VousEtes.vue'
import VousEtesDesc from '../views/VousEtesDesc.vue'
import Actualite from '../views/Actualite.vue'
import Actualites from '../views/Actualites.vue'
import Service from '../views/Service.vue'
import Contact from '../components/Contact.vue'
import LoginPage from '../views/LoginPage.vue'
import Recrutement from '../views/Recrutement.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/home"
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/missions',
    name: 'Missions',
    component: Missions
  },
  {
    path: '/recrutement',
    name: 'Recrutement',
    component: Recrutement
  },
  {
    path: '/vousEtes',
    name: 'VousEtes',
    component: VousEtes
  },
  {
    path: '/vousEtesDesc/:id',
    name: 'VousEtesDesc',
    component: VousEtesDesc,
    props(route) {
      return {
        pageid: route.params.id
      };
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/service',
    name: 'Service',
    component: Service
  },
  {
    path: '/actualites',
    name: 'Actualites',
    component: Actualites
  },
  {
    path: '/actualite/:id',
    name: 'Actualite',
    component: Actualite,
    props(route) {
      return {
        newsId: route.params.id
      };
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'Contact',
    component: Contact
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginPage
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior () {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  },  
  routes
})

export default router
```

---

When I go to my localhost:3000 the website is working fine, I can navigate threw the website, every pages is loaded correctly with the right data. So my VueJs front is working fine.

But when I try to refresh a page, I get `Cannot GET /pagename`

I've try multiples solutions, changing my routes names, changing the way I import them in my server.js, I always get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

> When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g.
> http://oursite.com/user/id. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client
> side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a
> 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their
> browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
> catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
> static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app
> lives in. Beautiful, again!

To fix this

For Node.js/Express, consider using [connect-history-api-fallback middleware.](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback)

Follow the documentation

To install the plugin

```
npm install --save connect-history-api-fallback
```

Import library

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
```

Add as a middleware

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(history({
    index: '/home.html'
});
```